# Connecting to a special wi-fi network via iPhone App

Tags: ios, ios4, wifi

I have to build an App that connects to a special Wi-Fi network and the opens an Ip address that is only available withing the network.

Is it possible to connect to a special wi-fi network (say "Network XYZ") via iPhone App. If so, please let know, so that I have an idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no. Not from within the app.

All you can do is instruct user to go to settings and connect to that network.

If iPhone was not registered to any WiFi network before entering your app and your app has usesWiFi key set to YES then user will get a list of available networks to choose from.

One more big problem is: there are no AdHoc networks on this list - only infrastructure networks. AdHoc networks are available only trough settings.

What you could do is to instruct your user to set the auto-join feature on for desired network.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only way to change the network is via the Settings application. Otherwise, rogue apps might be able to move users to their own proxies without the user's knowing.

It may be possible on jailbroken devices, however, as you would no longer be confined to working within the usual app restrictions on accessing system-level settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your app launch once the user connects to the SSID you specify using the CaptiveNetwork API.